# Replace City Names with ISO City codes in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to replace / add a new column to my dataframe which should contain city codes for the respective city name

Here's my dataframe

```
City
0   Alabama 
1   Alaska  
2   Arizona
3   Arkansas    
4   California
```

And I have another dataframe which has the city names with code

```
name    code
Alabama    US-AL
Alaska     US-AK
Arizona    US-AZ
Arkansas   US-AR
California US-CA
```

and here's my code

```
def iso(x):
    print(x)
    if x in list(country['name']):
        print(country[country['name']==x]['code'])
        return country[country['name']==x]['code'] 
    else:
        return ''

sales['city_code'] = sales['city'].apply(iso)
```

After running it I get this error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 50, placement implies 1
```

Comment: Have you try merge ?

Comment: Check out `map`: `sale['city_code']  = sale['city'].map(country.set_index('name')['code'])`

Comment: Hi, @Quang Hoang it's working. Thanks